# react js display loading on button on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple modal where I writte some data and submit to database. I'm trying to implement a simple loading on the button, so the user receives feedback. Unfortunately, this isn't working.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
 this.state = {
    isLoading: false, 
    show: false,
    list: []
    }
 }

onSubmit = async event => {
  ref.onSnapshot(async doc => {
    if (doc.data().status === 'accepted') {
      const list = await this.get(name, age, id);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        isLoading: !prevState.isLoading, // this doesn't work
        list: list,
        show: false // state for a modal
      }, () => console.log('loading on submit', this.state.isLoading)))
    }
   }
 }

<button
  onClick={this.onSubmit}
  disabled={this.state.isLoading ? true : false}>
  {this.state.isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'OK'}
</button>
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set `isLoading` to `true` before you get your data, and then set `isLoading` to `false` when the asynchronous request is complete.

**Example**

```js
function getList() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 2, 3]), 1000);
  });
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    show: false,
    list: []
  };

  onSubmit = event => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    getList().then(list => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        list,
        show: false
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.onSubmit}
        disabled={this.state.isLoading}
      >
        {this.state.isLoading ? "Loading..." : "OK"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**trigger loading true before await call like below code.**

```
   onSubmit = async event => {
   ref.onSnapshot(async doc => {
   if (doc.data().status === 'accepted') {
     this.setState({
       isLoading : true
     })
     const list = await this.get(name, age, id);
     this.setState(prevState => ({
       isLoading: false, 
       list: list,
       show: false // state for a modal
     }, () => console.log('loading on submit', this.state.isLoading)))
   }
  }
}
```